# How to show Legends inside linechart area

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to show legends inside the line chart plot area. By Default Legends are shown outside the graph plot area based on Side.RIGHT, Side.LEFT etc parameter been passed to chart.setLegendSide(Side) as in below example:-

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LineChartSample extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Month");
        final LineChart<String,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Graph Example");

        lineChart.setLegendSide(Side.RIGHT);

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("Legend 1");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 23));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 14));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 15));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 24));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 36));


        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("Legend 2");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 55));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 54));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 48));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 27));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 37));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 29));
        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);       
        lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I could not find way to show legends inside the graph area. At most i would have 2-3 legends and using java 8.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any clean way to do this.  I took out your `setLegendSide` and added this after `stage.show()`

```
    for (Node n : lineChart.lookupAll(".chart-legend")) {
        n.setTranslateY(-200);
    }
```

After the scene is showing, you can 'lookup' the nodes in the scene.  I find the legend (by it's css name) and move it up 200.

You can also translate the legend in a css file

```
.chart-legend{
     -fx-translate-y: -200;
}
```

Just add a css file to your scene (like this if it's in the same package).

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("css.css").toExternalForm());
```

This still leaves the space for it under the graph so it's not perfect.  I noticed you can add this the the css to give the `chart-content` more room

```
.chart .chart-content{
    -fx-padding: 5 5 -25 5;
}
```